# How can I display list of files in a directory?

Tags: shell-script, scripting

I created new directory called  dir1

Then I use touch command to add apple banana carrot date egg fish grape ham

After that I created file `Wildcards.sh` (incidentally I used nano to create the file).

```
#!/bin/bash

# This script will include wildcards

find . dir1
echo The contents of dir1 are:$find
echo
```

Then I executed it to test if it works. It did, but I don’t want it like this.

I ran it like `./Wildcards.sh`

And got

```
.
./ham
./egg
./grape
./date
./Wildcards.sh
./apple
./fish
./carrot
./banana
find: 'dir1': No such file or directory
The contents of dir1 are:
```

Should should output like this:
`The contents of dir1 are: apple banana carrot date egg fish grape ham`

Please help me find my mistake?

Comment: You learn by doing errors like these, that is perfectly fine, although I'd recommend reading up some Bash or POSIX tutorial first.

Comment: @LinuxSecurityFreak, I will lookup more explore on Bash, new inform about POSIX, I am still learning. Anyway, Thank you for your tip.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille, okay, my professor asked me to created directory make dir1 then make 8 files use touch command. After that create a shell script called Wildcard.sh.

Comment: @brocharvey, should we take it that you also want the filenames on a single line, separated by spaces, instead of each on a line of its own?

Answer (score 1):

You can't find dir1 when dir1 is your working directory. You never put anything in the variable "$find"

```
FIND=$(cd ~/dir1; echo *)

echo "The contents of dir1 are: $FIND"
```

What happens there, is that you change the working directory to dir1 in your home folder, and then let bash show you all contents that are not hidden ("*").  The results are saved in the variable FIND (but if there were errors, they'd be in FIND too).  If you want the hidden files and directories too, it would be:

```
FIND=$(cd ~/dir1; echo .* *)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here, Try

```
result=$(find ~/dir1)
echo "The contents of dir1 are: $result"
```

or

```
echo "The contents of dir1 are: $(find ~/dir1)"
```

### Breakdown:

(Forgive me if what I say is incorrect, I'm not the best with Bash)
`result=$(find ~/dir1)` runs `find ~/dir1` and then stores it in `result`,
 `$(command)` runs the command inside the `()`s and uses the STDOUT(Standard output/The output of the command) of the command as a temporary variable,
 You could also use `${result}` instead which allows for scenarios like `echo "${result}asdf"`.
Hope this helps! Forgive me for any improper formatting, This is my first post :P

Comment: Thank you for tip, but still have problem with long list.

Answer (score 0):

Your script with corrections.

```
#!/bin/bash

# This script has no wildcards

find_output="$(find dir1)"
echo 'The contents of dir1 are:'"$find_output"
echo
```

---

I thought I would add another answer, as all the existing ones have errors.

Some of your errors are:

- You seem to have assumed that the output of a process is put into a variable. It is not, unless you ask it to be.
- `find` does not need a `.` as its first argument. Yes it often does, but…
- The next problem is that you need to use the quotes. I don't think this caused a bug (yet). Some will be correct in saying that not all of the quotes are needed. However they are safe, and until you have totally mastered them, you may as well include them. After that you may as well include them.
- Then you have an incorrect comment. I hate comments, because they are almost always wrong. Comments should only say why, or be used if the language is too weak to express intention clearly.

---

## A note on the capitalisation of shell variables.

Shell variables should be lowercase. There is a standard for this. And you will get unexpected errors from time to time, if you make them capitals.

Comment: "Shell variable should be lowercase".  Better show us that standard.  I would also love to see such "unexpected error" because of a capitalized variable name.  And please, correct your spelling mistakes - I've counted 6 of them.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille This answer give an explanation and a link to a standard https://stackoverflow.com/a/52484424/537980

Comment: @GerardH.Pille I fixed several spelling errors. I don't think I found 6. Feel free to fix any that remain.

Comment: Impossible to edit just one character (thing => think).  Thanks anyhow, and for the link.  I must say, after 31 years of using uppercase variables, the error would indeed be unexpected.  I believe you'd need to export the variable before it could cause any harm - it could of course have been exported before you change it.

Comment: I did the edit. Soon you will be able to do this your self (thanks for spotting them). And yet the problem is the case where variable are already exported.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have other unmentioned requirements, the line you need is

```
echo The contents of dir1 are:$(ls dir1)
```

You can use it either in bash script or directly from command line. If you want to have the file names in a variable e.g. for future use then

```
files=$(ls Wallpapers)
echo The contents of dir1 are:$files
```